# Add a dependency on a task before the task is defined in Gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle, dependencies, task

I want to create a task that `dependsOn` `compileDebugJava`. However, the Java plugin creates the `compileDebugJava` task after I declare my dependency and Gradle returns:

> Task with path 'compileDebugJava' not found in project

So, is it  possible to state my dependency for a task that will be created later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradle has syntax for that:

```
task yourTask(dependsOn: 'compileDebugJava') {
    doLast {
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that the following equivalent syntax using the `<<` operator has been deprecated:

```
task yourTask(dependsOn: 'compileDebugJava') << {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very close to the solution. However, the "println" code runs when `compileDebugJava` is executed. What I want, it to run after `compileDebugJava` is added to the task list. So, I've refactored your solution: 
`project.afterEvaluate {
        javadoc.dependsOn compileDebugJavaWithJavac
}`

Comment: Could you then edit your question and rewrite it to say exactly what you want? There is a whole different solution that's better.

Comment: I think that my question expresses correctly what I want to achieve: add a dependency on a task that is not created yet. In my case, I can't call mytask.dependsOn compileDebugJavaWithJavac , because compileDebugJavaWithJavac  does not exist yet. Is there a solution specific to Javadoc?

Comment: OK, so just to be clear.  You already had an existing task defined elsewhere, then you wanted to make that task run in response to a task that has not been defined?  The solution to that is documented here in example 14.7.  https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html and yours is basically the same thing but with a few more lines.

Comment: No, that's not what I want. I want my task to depend on another task that will be defined later (not by me). In my case, `compileDebugJavaWithJavac` is defined later by the Java plugin. My task is `javadoc` and I want to make it depend on `compileDebugJavaWithJavac`.

Comment: Are you looking at the example titled: "Example 14.7. Lazy dependsOn - the other task does not exist (yet)"?

Comment: Sorry. I was not looking on section 14.5. You are right. This is what I was looking for. I remember trying that but without the quotes. The task name needs to be in quotes to define the lazy dependency? Can you update the answer to mark is as the right one?

Comment: I submitted an edit to change the syntax to use `doLast` since `<<` has been deprecated.

(It looks like it's awaiting review, but not 100% sure it got submitted correctly.)